# memory optimizing List<int[]>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I've made a Service that reads in several databases and load it in to another Database

the memory usage is Huge so now I'm looking in to reducing the memory usage.

I have a piece of code where I read in two colums from two diferent tables in to a list
my question is there a more memory effecient way to do this.

Currently there are about 3.4 million rows in the list and this number will only rise from now since the database this is taken from will only become bigger.

the code I'm talking about is initialized like this and used in a foreach loop:

```
    private List<int[]> DataIDList_1;
    private List<int[]> DataIDList_2;
    private List<int[]> DataIDList_3;
    public DatabaseTransferService()
    {
        DataIDList_1= new List<int[]>();
        DataIDList_2= new List<int[]>();
        DataIDList_3= new List<int[]>();
    }
    public void injectValues(docID,statID )
    {
          DataIDList_1.Add(new int[] { docID, statID });
    }
    public void insertData(List<int[]> DataIDList)
    {
        foreach (int[] intArrData in DataIDList)
        {
         int DataID = intArrData[0];
//Inserting data in to database based on the list
        }
    }
```

I've edited out the code that is not essential for my question.
for clarification the list contain only ID's on rows which I then use to fetch the row and insert the data from one db to another db.

Edit: I've left out the insert part of the database because it's not the part I'm looking at right now. I know there are probably something to get there also but I am currently looking at the single largest average memory user which in this case is my list's from the 3 databases.

Edit2: the idea I had was to load in all the ID's of the 5 databases and then load them in to the statistic database while only getting one row based on ID's in the list meaning the only thing I have in my memory is what I'm working on currently and ID's of all the rows
and just to clarify if there is a change in any of the rows in the 5 databases, I'll get to update the statistic database based on a revisionTable that I've also loaded the ID's in on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered moving the logic into the database? You can do powerful and efficient queries in SQL Server. For example, it's possible to write a query where rows are only inserted in one table if certain values exist in another table.

Comment: Did you profile your code to find what is consuming the most memory? I don't think that this code is a cause of your huge memory usage.

Comment: Got to agree with Mark here, database-to-database is the way forward. SQL Server has many tools to help with database replication.

Comment: why don't you "insertData" right where you put it into your memory-list

Comment: although I've put an answer I do agree completely that data import/export should be done in SQL

Comment: I think you left out most of the relevant stuff. Like how you fetch it and the toplevel algorithm. Solution #1 would be not to load all records at once.

Comment: the reason I don't do this in the database is because it's a service I would need to run periodically and I don't have that type of access to all the databases.

and the reson I've sepperated the insertData from where I fetch the Id's is because I've got several similar but not entirely equal databases so I'm reusing the select part in all but using different insertData in all of them.

It's practically imposible for me to get the accessrights to the database I would need to do anything in that area. so I'm left with having to try and optimize C# code.

Comment: I load all the records extract the ID and disband all the records. this means I will have a high memory usage in a peak. what I'm trying to do is to make the memory usage average go down since it's currently at around 1gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this kind of an interface between two databases? Maybe you could make us of `yield` here:

```
public IEnumerable<MyRecord> GetFromOriginalDB()
{
  // some fetching magic
  yield return myRecord;
}

public void WriteToTargetDB(IEnumerable<MyRecord> records)
{
  foreach(var record in records)
  {
    // insert magic
  }
}
```

The records should not be kept in memory (except from the very current one). However, this does require a lot of refactoring, given it works at all...

Comment: Not quiet what he asked for, but the idea of using IEnumerables is something he can surely develop to his needs.

Comment: the program is intented to read at about 5 databases (3 almost identical and 2 unknown) and insert it to one database for statistical programs. the one database that I load it in to is optimized and contain little to no renundance. the databases I take from are all production databases that are Very poorly table design if any at all and high renundance.

Comment: the idea I had was to load in all the ID's of the 5 databases and then load them in to the statistic database while only getting one row based on ID's in the list meaning the only thing I have in my memory is what I'm working on currently and ID's of all the rows